# in MySQL can I compare id FK with varchar in another table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have table with courseID, studentName and the other table is courseID , courseName  user will search for the course name in the student table based on the student name 
what sql syntax should I use ? join or inner join

Comment: `JOIN` is just short for `INNER JOIN`, so there is no difference. Then what exactly is the query supposed to do? A user enters a student name and a course name and gets 'yes' or 'no' depending on whether the student takes the course? Or a user enters a student name and gets all their courses? Or something else still? If you want to select data from both tables, a join would be the way to go. If you only show data from one table, however, a query with an exists clause may be more appropriate.

Comment: the user enter the student name and get all the course

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
select a.studentName,b.courseName 
from tbl_name a 
inner join tbl_name b
on a.courseID = b.courseID
```

Comment: This code has error as you have alias table but have not specified that name in selected column.

Comment: Yes I forgot to add alias name. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `JOIN` and specify a constraint (e.g. `on a.courseId = b.courseId`) it is exactly the same as if you use `INNER JOIN`, so according to your table structure you should do something like:

```
select * from studentTable
inner join courseTable 
on studentTable.courseID = courseTable.courseID
where studentTable.studentName = 'Jack Black';
```

In MySQL you could also write

```
select * from studentTable, courseTable 
where studentTable.courseID = courseTable.courseID
and studentName = 'Jack Black';
```

as it would internally be queried in the same way.

Check out the exact syntax for joins here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html

Comment: While it is still (more then twenty years after they were made redundant) *posible* to use comma-separated joins, we shouldn't recommend their use to beginners anymore.

Comment: Still, people should know that the possibility exists to use this kind of syntax as it is more common that one would expect.

Answer (score 0):

You join when you are looking for a joined result, such as select all student names along with all their courses. E.g.:

```
select s.studentname, c.coursename
from course c
join student_takes_course s on s.courseid = c.courseid;
```

or (as the order of the tables doesn't matter):

```
select s.studentname, c.coursename
from student_takes_course s
join course c on s.courseid = c.courseid;
```

`JOIN` is just short for `INNER JOIN`. You can use either.

But when you are not interested in the joined result, then it's a good habit not to join. Such as when you simply want to show the course names from the course table, as in your example. You would then use `IN` or `EXISTS` usually:

```
select coursename 
from course
where courseid in 
(
  select courseid
  from student_takes_course
  where studentname = 'Joe'
);
```

or

```
select c.coursename 
from course c
where exists
(
  select *
  from student_takes_course s
  where s.studentname = 'Joe'
  and s.courseid = c.courseid
);
```

(I prefer `IN` clauses over `EXISTS` clauses for their simplicity and use them when possible.)